# C# lambda Join multiple columns from one table to single column from another table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following data:

Games

```
Id | AwayTeamId | HomeTeamId |  SportId  |  foo  |  bar  |
------------------------------------------------------------
1  |      1     |     3      |     1     |  42   |  23   |
2  |      2     |     3      |     1     |  81   |  25   |
3  |      3     |     1      |     1     |  40   |  23   |
```

Teams

```
Id | TeamName  |
-----------------
1  |   Lions   |
2  |   Tigers  |
3  |   Bears   |
```

Sports

```
Id | SportName    |
--------------------
1  | Soccer       |
2  | Baseball     |
3  | Basketball   |
```

and I would like data like this for a `Game`

```
{
    "id": 2,
    "sport": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "soccer"
    }
    "awayTeam": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Tigers"
    },
    "homeTeam": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Bears"
    },
    "foo": 81,
    "bar": 25
}
```

Here's where I'm stuck: I know how to do a `join` for `Games` and `Teams` but don't know how to

1. have `Game.AwayTeamId` and `Game.HomeTeamId` both join on the same column in the `Teams` table
2. include the additional `Sport` lookup

Obviously I'm looking to make a single database call if possible.

Here is my C# code that I know is incomplete:

```
            var gameLookup = Context.Teams
                .Join(
                    Context.Games.Where(b => b.Id == id),
                    team => team.Id,
                    game => game.AwayTeamId,
                    (team, game) => new
                    {
                        game.Id,
                        AwayTeam = team,
                        game.foo,
                        game.bar
                    }
                ).FirstOrDefault();
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have relations set in your backend then it is simply:

```
var data = db.Games
             .Include(g => g.AwayTeam)
             .Include(g => g.HomeTeam)
             .Include(g => g.Sport)
             .Single(g => g.Id == 2);
var d = new {
        id = data.Id,
        sport = new {id = data.Sport.Id, name = data.Sport.SportName},
        awayTeam = new { id = data.AwayTeam.Id, name=data.AwayTeam.TeamName},
        homeTeam = new { id = data.HomeTeam.Id, name=data.HomeTeam.TeamName},
        foo = data.Foo,
        bar = data.Bar
    };
var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);   

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

As an example with MS SQL Server:

```
create table Sports (Id int primary key, SportName varchar(20));
insert into Sports (Id, SportName) values
(1,'Soccer'),
(2,'Baseball'),
(3,'Basketball');

create table Teams(Id int primary key, TeamName varchar(20));
insert into Teams (Id, TeamName) values 
(1,'Lions'),
(2,'Tigers'),
(3,'Bears');

create table Games(Id int primary key, 
    AwayTeamId int references Teams(Id),
    HomeTeamId int references Teams(Id),
    SportId int references Sports(Id), 
    foo  int,  bar int);
insert into Games (Id, AwayTeamId, HomeTeamId, SportId, foo, bar) values
(1, 1, 3, 1 ,42 ,23),
(2, 2, 3, 1 ,81 ,25),
(3, 3, 1, 1 ,40 ,23);
```

Above code generates this output:

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "sport": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Soccer"
  },
  "awayTeam": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Tigers"
  },
  "homeTeam": {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Bears"
  },
  "foo": 81,
  "bar": 25
}
```

Comment: My tables were previously not correctly setup, but I dropped and created them using basically the same SQL you included above.  Now when I try code like yours I get "Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid."

Comment: @AdamLeVasseur, it does work in EF.  Or instead of lambdas, you can do the Includes with strings of those table names. If you are using MS SQL Server, you might as well use LinqToSQL instead, which doesn't require those includes.

Comment: I had an issue in my model definition that was causing the lambda error.  Once I got that straightened out, your solution was exactly what I needed.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @AdamLeVasseur, I see. I should have included the full code, including Fluent API for mappings (BTW, dotnet ef is a great helpful tool in that regard).

Answer (score 1):

Use `.Include` as mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data

```
 var gameLookup = Context.Games.Include(t=>t.AwayTeam).Include(t=>t.HomeTeam)
                         .Include(t=>t.AwayTeam).Include(t=>t.Sports)....
```